# Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 - Excel to SQL Data Migration

Tags: sql, sql-server

**I am having this error when migrating data from excel sheet to sql database table. Below is my code;**

```
INSERT INTO Employee
                         ( Emp_Prefix,EmpCardNumber, CostCenterCode, PayCenterCode, BasisOfPay, WorkingTime, BasisAmount, Title, Surname, First_Names, 
                         Resident, Address, PostalAddress, Post_Code, Telephone, TelephoneOffice, TelephoneMobile, Sex, DOB, EmailAddress, EmailOffice, Nationality, Village, TAuthority, 
                         District, Religion, DrivingLicenseNo, PassportNo, Marital_Status, Kin_Name, Kin_Relationship, Kin_Telephone, Spouse, Memo, Date_Joined, DesignationCode, 
                         GradeCode, DepartmentCode, ConfirmedDate, Gratuity, GratuityRate, GratuityAmount, GratuityBalance, GratuityEffDate, Pensionable, PensionEffDate, 
                         Payment_Method, Probation, ProbationEndDate, ContractStartDate, ContractEndDate, ETIN, EmployerContr, EmpContr,   Status
                         )
SELECT    'P' as prifix, 0 as empcard, 'HO' AS COSTCENT,'OPM' as Paycent  ,  'M' AS BASICPAY, 1 AS WORKTIME,isnull( [Basic Salary] ,0) as Basicpay,isnull(Title,'') ,ISNULL(Surname,''),
isnull([First Name],''),'' AS RESID , isnull(Address,''), ISNULL(Address,'') AS POSTAD , '265' AS POSTCODE ,'' as Telephone ,''  AS OFFTEL ,'' as [Mobile Number] ,
 ISNULL(Gender,''), isnull([Dat of Birth],'') as DOB ,'' as [Email Address] ,'' AS EMAILOFF ,'Malawian' as Nation ,'' as village ,'' as Tauth, '' as distr ,
 '' as Relign , '' as drvlicen , '' as passport , ISNULL([Marriage Status],'') , '' as kinname , '' as KinRel , '' as Kin_Tel , '' as spouse ,'' as memo,
isnull( [Joined Date],'') as DateJoin ,'' as desig ,isnull([Grade Code],'') as Grdcode ,ISNULL(Department_Code,'') ,isnull( [Confirmed Data],'') as ConfDate ,0 as gartuity ,0 as GratRate, 0 as GratAmt ,  0 as grabal , '' as GratDate, 
 CASE WHEN Pensionable ='Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as pensio  ,
 '' as Pensdate , isnull([Pay Method],'') as PayMeth , '0' as Proba ,isnull( [Probation End Date],'') as probdate , '' as contractSTdate ,'' as contractEnddate ,'' as ETIN ,isnull([Company Contributin],'') as emplcontr ,isnull( [Employee Contribution],'') as Emplyecontr ,  
 '0' as statuss 
FROM        [dbo].[Sheet1$]
```

Comment: An error message is more helpful than an unreadable wall of code.

Comment: Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: Well, obviously you're trying to insert a varchar value into a numeric column. Since you didn't share any info on the table structure, you're the only one who can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Excel import often can't create the correct column type and the empty cells becames empty string '' where maybe you need a null number. Check the structure of Sheet1$ table and Employee table

Comment: Thanks @Antonio Campagnaro. Will go through the structure again.